# AIR: Android file delete leaves empty placeholder in Gallery

Tags: android, mobile, air, gallery, air-android

I'm having the same problem as in this question in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4430888/891148). But I'm not doing my application with Java but with ActionScript and Adobe AIR 2.6.

Then the question is how to get rid of the placeholders via ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Air3.0, create a native extension, and call a Java function with this code

taken from: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html

```
// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
}
});
```