# Android: How to notify MediaScanner that contents deleted?

Tags: android, sqlite, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I'm now developing Android app using MediaScanner, and now I can access to contents data managed by Sqlite database and refresh the newly added contents using scanFile method.

What I want to do is to refresh (update) the data of Sqlite managed by MediaStore.

I powered off and on Android then I can start MediaScanner explicitly and then I can refresh data on Sqlite MediaStore, however, I don't know how to notify MediaScanner that contents (such as MP3 sound files and JPEG image files) are deleted while Android is turned on.

Could you kindly tell me how to notify the content file deletion for MediaScanner and update the Sqlite data on MediaStore?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430888/android-file-delete-leaves-empty-placeholder-in-gallery