# Android Deleting Files MediaScannerConnection

Tags: java, android, file, delete-file, android-mediascanner

I'm trying to delete some files or directories from the internal memory (ASUS TF101) using the commands File.delete(). However, using the Android File explorer I can see how the files are removed, but using the Windows explorer they still show there.

I solved a similar issue when adding files just creating a MediaScannerConection (and using the method scanFile).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Of course it´s not acceptable to restart the device as the final user will not like this "solution".

Answer (score 3):

See the answer of **manisha** in this thread: [Android file delete leaves empty placeholder in Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430888/android-file-delete-leaves-empty-placeholder-in-gallery)

In my case, it worked fine because i was saving a photo and then scanning it using the MediaScannerConnection, so when the scan finishes i have the URI of that file and then i can use the following code whitout problems.

```
getContentResolver().delete(imageUri, null, null);
```

Hope this works for you. This seems to be more suitable than forcing a SD Card remount by sending an intent to android system.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. I have tried so many methods but none of them worked in android 4.2 but  your suggestion worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found the answear:

Android uses a media table to handle files. When you make changes to a file, you must update this table.

Try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Google doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

Comment: This no longer work since Android 4.4 KitKat, reference https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57915